# TestLink - import XML - "Test Plan Usage"

Tags: manual-testing, testlink

My test cases are in Excel and have found the ability to import them into TestLink via XML very useful.

My query is around "Add to Test Plans" flag, I have to set this individually for each test case in order to see them in Execute Test (this is time consuming).

I have exported a test case where "Add to Test Plans" have been selected and another test case where it has not been selected.

There seems to be no difference in the XML files?

Can "Add to Test Plans" flag be set in my XML file prior to importing my test cases??